# Sequence $a(n)$ where limit $n$ tends to infinity.

Tags: sequences-and-series

$a_1 = 1$
$a_2 = \frac{e}{2}$
$a_3 = \frac{e^2}{4}$
$a_4 = \frac{e^3}{8}$
$\dots$
Limit n tends to infinity.
Is this forming a GP? If yes then why when I apply formula of infinite GP I am having problem finding answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a GP. However you can only use the sum to infinity formula when the sum actually exists. As the common ratio $\frac{e}{2}>1$ then the sum to infinity doesn't exist.

Comment: Does this mean that answer should be infinity?

Comment: Infinity isn't a number. Saying it adds to infinity is one way to think of it. Its probably better to say that the partial sums diverge to infinity.

Comment: The question that I asked is Multiple type and options are a) 0 b) 1 c) e^e d) infinite   I meant to ask is the most probable option d?

Comment: Given those options, Yes the answer is d. Note it says that the answer is infinite (verb), implying without limit as opposed to infinity (noun) which is different but related.

Comment: @ItiShree Welcome to Math.SE. please add your previous comment data to the question. It may help you get answer faster and better. Also you can learn LaTeX (only a little bit) to improve the question visuals.

Comment: @MayankM. thanks I  just joined so surely I'll look forward to it.

Comment: @IanMiller thanks that helps.